# Loss of quality of aerial photo when removing black boarder of georeferenced tiff

Tags: qgis

[image]Can someone assist? When georeferenceing a black and white aerial tiff, I can remove the black background, but it makes the aerial slightly transparent. How do I make the aerial less trasnparent again, and maintain the quality of the original tiff?

Qgis

Comment: I can't understand what happens from your literal description. Sample data and screenshots might help.

Comment: I have attached a screen shot showing the clarity of the aerial photo before the black is removed and after. After the black is removed the clarity fades to almost transparent and I lose a lot of detail in the aerial.How do I avoid losing this clarity in the image? Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: How did you remove the Black border?

Comment: I somehow feel that you are doing some unnecessary things but you do not still explain what you have been doing. Think it so that someone else should be able to follow your path from start to end. But have you simply tried to open the Properties-Transparency of your middle aerial image and set the No data value into "0" which makes only the black pixels fully transparent.